# Magento Order Invoices - Text TINY, how do I enlarge it?

Tags: magento

When printing invoices (PDF) from Magento, the font is 7px... it's absolutely tiny, half my customers probably won't be able to read it, is there a way to make it 12+?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/31533/) entry on the magento message boards you need to edit these files:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php 
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php 
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php
```

and change the second parameter, which is the font size, to the number you want on these methods:

```
_setFontRegular(), _setFontBold(), and _setFontItalic()
```

Comment: Yeah I found and tried that, the line spacing doesn't seem to also increase, so I'm left with overlapping text. :/ Any ideas?

Comment: You may need to dive into the ZendFramework, as linked on that page, to try and change the line spacing. You will probably need to alter co-ordinates of blocks of text in any case. That page talks about decreasing y values.

Comment: [This wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf) may be of use as well. Also, it may be easier to simply change the DPI resolution of the PDF. I don't know how this is done in Zend_PDF, but the font sizes are being specified in points, so a lower DPI would increase their relative size.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the files in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/` you need to change the different fonts.

But if you set the font or size, so the text becomes bigger you need to find all the places in the code where it says $this->y -=XX; (most xx=10) and change all these places to a higher number if you change the font size.

Another way is to use my extension, where you can make all the pdf's from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add on some numbers where it has `$this->y`.
I also have a newly-updated extension which [creates great-looking PDFs](http://www.moogento.com/magento-pickpack-picklist.html) that you can fully customize.